# Compress large file using SharpZipLib causing Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, compression, out-of-memory, sharpziplib

I have a 453MB XML file which I'm trying to compress to a ZIP using [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/).

Below is the code I'm using to create the zip, but it's causing an `OutOfMemoryException`. This code successfully compresses a file of 428MB.

Any idea why the exception is happening, as I can't see why, as my system has plenty of memory available.

```
public void CompressFiles(List<string> pathnames, string zipPathname)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(zipPathname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (ZipOutputStream stream2 = new ZipOutputStream(stream))
            {
                foreach (string str in pathnames)
                {
                    FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(str, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream3.Length];
                    try
                    {
                        if (stream3.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error reading '{0}'.", str));
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        stream3.Close();
                    }
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(str));
                    stream2.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    stream2.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                stream2.Finish();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        File.Delete(zipPathname);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to create a buffer as big as the file. Instead, make the buffer a fixed size, read some bytes into it, and write the number of read bytes into the zip file.

Here's your code with a buffer of 4096 bytes (and some cleanup):

```
public static void CompressFiles(List<string> pathnames, string zipPathname)
{
    const int BufferSize = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(zipPathname,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        using (ZipOutputStream stream2 = new ZipOutputStream(stream))
        {
            foreach (string str in pathnames)
            {
                using (FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(str,
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(str));
                    stream2.PutNextEntry(entry);

                    int read;
                    while ((read = stream3.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        stream2.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                }
            }
            stream2.Finish();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        File.Delete(zipPathname);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Especially note this block:

```
const int BufferSize = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// ...
int read;
while ((read = stream3.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    stream2.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

This reads bytes into `buffer`. When there are no more bytes, the `Read()` method returns 0, so that's when we stop. When `Read()` succeeds, we can be sure there is *some* data in the buffer but we don't know how many bytes. The whole buffer might be filled, or just a small portion of it. Therefore, we use the number of read bytes `read` to determine how many bytes to write to the `ZipOutputStream`.

That block of code, by the way, can be replaced by a simple statement that was added to .Net 4.0, which does exactly the same:

```
stream3.CopyTo(stream2);
```

So, your code could become:

```
public static void CompressFiles(List<string> pathnames, string zipPathname)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(zipPathname,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        using (ZipOutputStream stream2 = new ZipOutputStream(stream))
        {
            foreach (string str in pathnames)
            {
                using (FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(str,
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(str));
                    stream2.PutNextEntry(entry);

                    stream3.CopyTo(stream2);
                }
            }
            stream2.Finish();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        File.Delete(zipPathname);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And now you know why you got the error, and how to use buffers.

Comment: Thanks. Im stuck using .Net 2.0 which is why your answer which contains both has been accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You're allocating a lot of memory for no good reason, and I bet you have a 32-bit process. 32-bit processes can only allocate up to 2GB of virtual memory in normal conditions, and the library surely allocates memory too.

Anyway, several things are wrong here:

- `byte[] buffer = new byte[stream3.Length];`

  Why? You don't need to store the whole thing in memory to process it.
- `if (stream3.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)`

  This one is nasty. `Stream.Read` is explicitly allowed to return *less* bytes than what you asked for, and this is still a valid result. When reading a stream into a buffer you have to call `Read` repeatedly until the buffer is filled or the end of the stream is reached.
- Your variables should have more meaningful names. You can easily get lost with these `stream2`, `stream3` etc.

A simple solution would be:

```
using (var zipFileStream = new FileStream(zipPathname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(zipFileStream))
{
    foreach (string str in pathnames)
    {
        using(var itemStream = new FileStream(str, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(str));
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
            itemStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
        }
    }
    zipStream.Finish();
}
```

Comment: `Stream.CopyTo` is more readable than my do..while loop, have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks. Ill make a note of this for future projects but im stuck on .Net 2.0 for this one. I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Sure, in that case the `while` loop is appropriate, but you may also use SharpZipLib's `StreamUtils.Copy` function instead.